# Thymeleaf editing th:field before action

Tags: thymeleaf

I have a simple pagination that looks like

```
<ul class="pagination justify-content-end" th:field="*{page}">                
    <li class="page-item page-item disabled">
        <a class="page-link" href="action">1</a>
     </li>          
</ul>
```

I would get the following behaviour with Thymeleaf. Clicking on the page and before submitting the action, the value of the th:field associated with the pagination should be changed  by setting it to the th:value of the selected page. In other words, clicking on the page number should change the value of "*{page}" and then call the method. Is there any way to do that, for example, combining  th:onclick with th:action?

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf is a rendering engine, as such it can do nothing once the page is served to the end user. At best u can fill variables into javascript when rendering to achieve the desired result.

As for your described functionality the given code is far to limited or faulty to give a suggestion for a javascript solution, for one th:field on a non-input element doesn't do much. Also the shown href is just a simple href that doesnt interact in any way with the encapsulating th:field.

Comment: More in general, I have a post method that should be called when clicking on the mentioned href. On server side I also need the number of the clicked page (that I would take by bean binding). Is there any changed to do so?

Comment: Could do something like `th:href="@{/your/path(pageNumber=${yourPageNumberVariable})}` to get an url like `localhost:8080/yourapp/your/path?pageNumber=1` which would be a get request, if you want posts you need to work with forms not `a` elements.

Comment: So, I guess that I can use an hidden input in the latter case